# Two objects oscillating out of phase in water, do they attract?

Tags: resonance

Two objects in water oscillate out of phase, close enough for waves to influence one another, do they attract?

Comment: For two objects to attract, a force must draw them together. Is there such a force here?

Comment: What are your own thoughts Gert?

Comment: No attraction IMO...

Comment: Bjerknes original experiments were based around this topic. His idea was that hydrodynamic waves from pulsating or oscillating objects, had similar effects as electromagnetic waves. When the waves cancelled out between the objects, they would tend to attract, and when waves combined, they would repel. He showed this experimentally in water. https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=coo.31924064490133&view=1up&seq=7